# No such element exception but the element is clearly there

Tags: java, android, automation, appium, nosuchelementexception

I am trying to write code that automates an **android** app to do everything you would do with your fingers.

The goal now is to get it to select a picture. I typed this line so it selects the element through the resource-id from uiautomatorviewer.

`driver.findElement(By.id("com.offerup:id/photo_image_view")).click();`

[image]

But when I run my code, this is what shows up in my Appium server log.

```
`[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.offerup:id/photo_image_view' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.offerup:id/photo_image_view]
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Finding 'com.offerup:id/photo_image_view' using 'ID' with the contextId: '' multiple: false
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.offerup:id/photo_image_view]
[AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 7 to NoSuchElementError
[AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":7,"value":"No element found"}
[W3C (3ce51f1a)] Encountered internal error running command: NoSuchElementError: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

`

I'm not sure what the problem is, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

use the following xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id,'photo_image_view')]")).click();
```

Comment: No success, my console stops executing code when it wants to run this command, it doesn't even give me an exception.